# How to enable s3 support instead of minio for milvus v2.0.0?

Tags: amazon-s3, minio

I'm trying to use s3 as object storage instead of minio but I'm unable to find the proper flags in docker-compose or configs to enable that. If anyone can point me where I should look for the flag or what are the right flags for this that would be great. I have gone the code base but have not been able to come up with useful information regarding this.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use s3 as storage. You can read about it here (https://milvus.io/docs/v2.0.0/deploy_s3.md).

Basically, you would need to:

1. modify the milvus.yaml file according to the tutorial above (get it from here: `https://github.com/milvus-io/milvus/blob/master/configs/milvus.yaml`)
2. modify docker-compose.yml: map the path of the locally modified configuration file to the file path of Milvus 2.0 milvus.yaml

For example, if you modified the milvus.yaml and stored it in path `/home/milvus.yaml`, in docker-compose.yml, you need to this line: `/home/milvus.yaml:/milvus/configs/milvus.yaml` in `standalone/volumes`